# Triggering an action during response in outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-app

I want to take an action when user responds to an email in outlook and owa(Outlook Web Access). Is it possible to take control of the action using javascript? After going through the docs, I didn't see a way to do this. I thought of checking what others are doing.

Comment: You can define an event handler as explained in this [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278814/vba-macro-customize-reply-button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about Office.js API, the answer is no. This API is based on user invocation of particular add-in and doesn't support events.

Comment: any other way trigger an event while replaying event?

Comment: I believe @Axel Kemper already provided with the hint by using VB Macro. Yet another way would be to use COM/VSTO add-ins technology to build plugin for Desktop Outlook on Windows. This technology fully supports Outlook events.